# No UserInfo when calling acquireToken()

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

When retrieving an access token using acquireToken() like this:

`Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", credential, null);
AuthenticationResult result = future.get();`

Result: The UserInfo in object AuthenticationResult is null.

But when aquiring access token like this:

`Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(currentUri), credential, null);
AuthenticationResult result = future.get();`

Result: I get UserInfo in object AuthenticationResult.

How do I get UserInfo data using the first case?

Comment: Does `credential` contain a client id and secret? If so, which user's info are you expecting to get when you authenticate with only your app's keys?